# Convert Wstring to CString

Tags: cstring, wstring

i have a variable of Cstring,need to convert it to wstring.

Comment: What platform? Which framework? Which library? What have you tried so far?

Comment: windows, i have code in visual studio

Answer (score 1):

The [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072(VS.85).aspx) function is the base level Win32 API function to do this. Whatever library or framework you are using may offer a more convenient function that wraps this operation.